# How can i send email templates from angular with help of node js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, angular8, email-templates

I want to send email templates through angular and node js. i'm getting values from angular.I'm trying to send email template using angular and node js but i cant send the mail.
node js code is below

server.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
express = require('express');
cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const details = require("./details.json");
```

//Init app

```
const app = express();
```

//Cross Connection

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));
```

//Body parser middleware

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

//Define Port

```
port = 3000;
```

//start server

```
 app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Server is running at port: ${port}`);
});

transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: details.email,
        pass: details.password,
    },
}),
EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate,
path = require('path'),
Promise = require('bluebird');

function sendEmail (obj) {
    return transporter.sendMail(obj);
}
```

//Function for template selection

```
function loadTemplate (templateName, contexts) {
let template = new EmailTemplate(path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 
templateName));
return Promise.all(contexts.map((context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        template.render(context, (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve({
                email: result,
                context,
            });
        });
    });
}));
}
```

// Get values from Angular

```
app.post('/sendmail', function (req, res){
let rgData = req.body;

loadTemplate('registration', rgData).then((results) => {
    return Promise.all(results.map((result) => {
        sendEmail({
            to: result.context.email,
            from: 'Felix Its :)',
            subject: result.email.subject,
            html: result.email.html,
            text: result.email.text,
        });
    }));
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Email Successfully Sent');
});


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
        res.render('index');
});

});
```

this is code for send email template ..
im geting values from angular and send to node file.

Comment: what is your errors

Answer (score 0):

You should grant permissions for the email address used in this service to send emails.